# How can I create a TableLayoutPanel in VB Dynamically?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a tableLayoutPanel by code in Windows Form VB which can later be coded to add on extra rows and columns also by coding

Comment: A table? What kind of table? Please read carefully [ask] and take a tour of the [help] before asking

Comment: This really isn't a lot to go on. It will be flagged as _too broad_. Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What kind of table?

Comment: DataTable, TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel or maybe a DataGridView?  If you want a good answer you have to ask a good question.

Comment: TableLayoutPanel plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the form starts:

`Private Sub form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _MyBase.Load
          Dim TLP As New TableLayoutPanel 
         'Edit all your properties: name, size, location, etc.
End Sub`

Say when you click a button1:

`Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Me.Controls.Add(TLP)
End Sub`

Hope that helps.